# how to track scan on other servers?

Tags: networking, server, tcpdump

I have an issue with users abusing the server resources and connections.

I have a server with access to several users. one of them is performing network scans abusing the network.

I tried using tcpdump but with no luck as i don't know how to be searching for the right information,all i have is the analysis from the data center.

I have also tried spotting the traffic via iftop and syslog.

Can you help ?

Comment: Please, explain me. Users from server abuse network with scan's or ?

Comment: have a corporate VPN configured.the logs on it does not provide much info.

now i get abuse notices from data center due to network scans.

they provide the exit port from my server and the local IP and port of the device attacked/scanned

how to spot this user ?

Comment: your vpn user from your server scans network? User connect to your vpn server and run scan from server?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With command, if you use pptp server

```
last |grep ppp
```

will see, something like this

```
xxxxx1   ppp0         xxx.xxx.xx.5     Fri Oct 30 11:19   still logged in   
xxxxx1   ppp0         xxx.xxx.xx.5     Fri Oct 30 11:18 - 11:19  (00:00)    
xxxxx1   ppp0         xxx.xxx.xx.5     Fri Oct 30 11:17 - 11:18  (00:01)    
xxxxx    ppp0         xxx.xxx.xx.6     Fri Oct 30 11:13 - 11:16  (00:03)    
xxxxx    ppp0         xxx.xxx.xx.6     Wed Oct  7 12:37 - 12:50  (00:13)    
xxxxx    ppp0         xxx.xxx.xx.6     Wed Oct  7 12:34 - 12:35  (00:01)
```

pptp user. connection duration also start and end. 
Based on time of abuse you can compare time of vpn connection and find vpn user. I guess, one person use one vpn user.

You can add fixed ip address per vpn user and after that monitoring traffic with `iptables` Very nice example to set `ip accounting` you have [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/traffic-accounting-with-iptables/)